# Validate values in OSX bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I read from apple documentation that I can use a sort of validation for KVC using the function `validate<Key>:error:` but I can't understand how this functions is called for values bind from IB.

I've added `validateMyKey:error` in the controller that uses a xib where I've defined a bind over the key `myKey` but whenever I change value from the interface, the function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a typo in your question, but it should be:

```
validateMyKey:error:
```

with a lower-case "e". That is in line with normal Cocoa naming practices.